# LG 31MU97-B monitor support on rMBP 15"

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport, display

I want to buy LG 31MU97-B as a new external monitor for my Macbook Pro Retina 15" late 2013 with Intel Iris Pro only. But this monitor has real 4k resolution of 4096 x 2160!

Can i get this resoluton at 60Hz on my rMBP?

Comment: Just a thought to be clear and say the LG Website shows support for the Late 2013 MacBook Pro 15" like mine please note withthe GeForce GT 750M* Graphics card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid not.

From [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.0-15-iris-only-late-2013-retina-display-specs.html)

> *This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 2560x1600 on two external displays via Thunderbolt. Alternately, it can support a single display up to 2560x1600 via Thunderbolt and a single 1080p display at up to 60 Hz, 3840x2160 at 30 Hz, or 4096x2160 at 24 Hz via HDMI.

From [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202856)

> You can use 4K displays and Ultra HD TVs at the following resolutions and refresh rates via the built-in HDMI port.
>   3840 x 2160 at 30 Hz refresh rate
>   4096 x 2160 at 24 Hz refresh rate (mirroring is not supported at this resolution)

Comment: it says "4096x2160 at 24 Hz via HDMI", what about DP?

Comment: for this, TB/DP are one & the same.

Comment: But seems, Yosemite would support it at 50Hz: http://www.jailbreakmodo.com/lg-31um97-mac-supported-4k-monitor.html

Comment: over HDMI @ 24Hz. Answer updated.

Comment: At least at 50Hz would be ok, but 24Hz is too irritating.

Comment: then you'll need to wait until Apple releases a machine or update that enables it. Even the Mac Pro can't do it as yet.

Comment: Yep. On offical LG website it says: MBPr late 2013 can run full res at 50Hz with OSX 10.10. http://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/lg-31MU97
LOL!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the MAcbook pro late 2013 and it worked at 50Hz with my LG31MU97.  Upgraded now to latest Mid 2015 macbook pro and the rate is 60Hz.   For me the macbook screen is closed this might make a difference. I understand you need the very latest OSX

The only snag for me with the macbook screen closed was the need to restart the Macbook to get the 50Hz after sleep.  (The LG did not wake sometimes it does and then at 30Hz)

I did have a display delivered from Amazon warehouse that did not go above 30Hz I had both Macbooks at the time to try and so sent it back.   The replacement was quick and the new LG monitor worked at 50Hz on the Late 2013 machine and 60Hz on the Late 2015 MacBook with GPU.

I could not tell and difference between 50 and 60Hz but at 30Hz it makes the mouse appear to lag/jump. Hope that helps!